# Set range value sets only the first value

Tags: c#, excel, office-addins, excel-addins

To set a range of Excel values, I use this code:

```
int[] values = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
String rangeStart = "A1";
String rangeEnd = "A3";

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets objSheets;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet workSheet;

objBook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
objSheets = objBook.Worksheets;
workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)objBook.ActiveSheet;

workSheet.Range[rangeStart, rangeEnd].Value = values;
```

But the cells contain only the first value of the array.
Any ideas how to write every array value into the fields?

Comment: **IF** this were VBA, the array would need to be 2D.  Perhaps the same in **C#**?

Answer (score 2):

As @Ron Rosenfield says, Excel ranges are 2-dimenional arrays. So,

```
int[,] values = new int[,] { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 } };
```

will work for you. Always remember - 2d arrays